# Do undocumented students lose their enrollment in universities if they are expelled?

Tags: united-states, immigration, academia, illegal-immigration

In the US, [undocumented students](https://undocumented.harvard.edu/) can apply to universities. If one such student is accepted and enrolled but later deported due to not being covered by DACA or other reasons, will their enrollment be cancelled? That is, will they have to begin the admission process again like a first-time student? If not, if they make it back to the US (il)legally, can they resume their studies where they left off?

Comment: Wouldn't the student complete an application to the University, and in the process of doing so, become documented?

Comment: This is entirely up to each educational institution's admissions office. No federal immigration law governs this issue, private educational institutions have no legal regulation in  this regard, and in most states, this is up to the governing bodies of public educational institutions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about university policy and not law.

Comment: @MichaelHall not really.  DACA recipients have more rights than people in student status. A DACA beneficiary who changed to student status would basically be committing to leaving the US at the end of their studies.  Someone who is in the US illegally is also likely to be barred from obtaining nonimmigrant status as a student or otherwise.

Comment: @phoog, my question has nothing to do with various rights afforded to those in certain categories, it's about the inappropriateness of the euphemism "undocumented" in the case of someone who's status is actually well documented.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open. ohwilleke is correct that this is about university policy and not law, I think that in itself is the correct answer to the question. It is likely that the querent may've been unaware of that, so being made aware is thus a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

No law requires the expulsion of a student who is deported while enrolled in classes, nor any law forbidding enrolling a student lacking in the appropriate immigration paperwork. It is possible that some college has such a policy. [Here](http://www.washington.edu/admin/rules/policies/SGP/SPCH209.html#7) is the code of conduct section for one university stating under what circumstances on can be expelled, so you can see that this place can't expel you for being deported.